# Keras model.fit ValueError: Shapes (None, 43) and (None, 1, 1, 43) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

EDIT: I added a Flatten() layer in between the ResNet50 and the Dense layer and the error is gone

I'm very new to using Keras and machine learning in general. My goal is to use the Keras ResNet50 model pretrained with ImageNet weights to classify between different types of signs in the GTSRB. I am using Google CoLab and the code to load and preprocess all the images/labels was written by my professor. I can compile and predict with the model, the issue I have is with training. I am using the model.fit() function to try and train the model.

The images are 32x32 images so I set the input_tensor to have a shape of (32, 32, 3). There are 43 labels to classify from and I'm using one-hot encoding so I added a layer of size 43 after the ResNet50. I'm not sure where the ValueError is coming up exactly, but I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the labels. I really don't know what the issue with the shapes is, I've been looking through documentation and other Stack Overflow answers but I can't find anything that applies to this (with my limited understanding).

Here are the errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-21-2f55b5d19997> in <module>()
      6 
      7 resnet.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['acc'])
----> 8 resnet.fit(x=imgs_train, y=labels_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NUM_EPOCH, validation_data=(imgs_val, labels_val))
      9 
     10 predictions = resnet.predict(x=imgs_test)

9 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:789 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:201 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:141 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:245 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:1666 categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:4839 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 43) and (None, 1, 1, 43) are incompatible
```

Here's my code:

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, decode_predictions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import cv2
from itertools import chain
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

### Load data

# Path to project directory
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Assignment1/'

# Path to directory containing the dataset
DATA_DIR = PROJECT_ROOT_DIR + 'Data/'

# Function for loading the dataset
# Code from advml-traffic-sign (https://github.com/inspire-group/advml-traffic-sign)
def load_dataset_GTSRB(n_channel=3, train_file_name=None):
    """
    Load GTSRB data as a (datasize) x (channels) x (height) x (width) numpy
    matrix. Each pixel is rescaled to the range [0,1].
    """

    def load_pickled_data(file, columns):
        """
        Loads pickled training and test data.

        Parameters
        ----------
        file    : string
                          Name of the pickle file.
        columns : list of strings
                          List of columns in pickled data we're interested in.

        Returns
        -------
        A tuple of datasets for given columns.
        """

        with open(file, mode='rb') as f:
            dataset = pickle.load(f)
        return tuple(map(lambda c: dataset[c], columns))

    def preprocess(x, n_channel):
        """
        Preprocess dataset: turn images into grayscale if specified, normalize
        input space to [0,1], reshape array to appropriate shape for NN model
        """

        if n_channel == 3:
            # Scale features to be in [0, 1]
            x = (x / 255.).astype(np.float32)
        else:
            # Convert to grayscale, e.g. single Y channel
            x = 0.299 * x[:, :, :, 0] + 0.587 * x[:, :, :, 1] + \
                0.114 * x[:, :, :, 2]
            # Scale features to be in [0, 1]
            x = (x / 255.).astype(np.float32)
            x = x[:, :, :, np.newaxis]
        return x

    # Load pickle dataset
    if train_file_name is None:
        x_train, y_train = load_pickled_data(
            DATA_DIR + 'train.p', ['features', 'labels'])
    else:
        x_train, y_train = load_pickled_data(
            DATA_DIR + train_file_name, ['features', 'labels'])
    x_val, y_val = load_pickled_data(
        DATA_DIR + 'valid.p', ['features', 'labels'])
    x_test, y_test = load_pickled_data(
        DATA_DIR + 'test.p', ['features', 'labels'])

    # Preprocess loaded data
    x_train = preprocess(x_train, n_channel)
    x_val = preprocess(x_val, n_channel)
    x_test = preprocess(x_test, n_channel)
    return x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test

# Set constants (GTSRB)
NUM_LABELS = 43                             # Number of labels
BATCH_SIZE = 32                             # Size of batch
HEIGHT = 32                                 # Height of input image
WIDTH = 32                                  # Width of input image
N_CHANNEL = 3                               # Number of channels
OUTPUT_DIM = 43                             # Number of output dimension

# Set training hyperparameters
NUM_EPOCH = 100                             # Number of epoch to train
LR = 0.0001                                 # Learning rate

INPUT_SHAPE = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, N_CHANNEL)  # Input shape of model
IMG_SHAPE = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, N_CHANNEL)

# Load the images and labels
imgs_train, labels_train, imgs_val, labels_val, imgs_test, labels_test = load_dataset_GTSRB(n_channel=N_CHANNEL)

# Display the shapes of train, validation, and test datasets
print('Images train shape: {} - Labels train shape: {}'.format(imgs_train.shape, labels_train.shape))
print('Images validation shape: {} - Labels validation shape: {}'.format(imgs_val.shape, labels_val.shape))
print('Images test shape: {} - Labels test shape: {}'.format(imgs_test.shape, labels_test.shape))

# Display the range of images (to make sure they are in the [0, 1] range)
print('\nMax pixel value', np.max(imgs_train))
print('Min pixel value', np.min(imgs_train))
print('Average pixel value', np.mean(imgs_train))
print('Data type', imgs_train[0].dtype)

# Read the sign names
signnames = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + 'signnames.csv').values[:, 1]

# Plot a few images to check if the data makes sense (note that the quality of some of the images is pretty low)
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
for n in range(9):
    i = np.random.randint(0, len(imgs_train), 1)
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, n+1)
    plt.imshow(imgs_train[i[0]])
    plt.title('Label:' + str(signnames[labels_train[i[0]]]))
    plt.axis('off')

# Convert the labels to one-hot encoding (to input to the models)
labels_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels_train, NUM_LABELS)
labels_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels_test, NUM_LABELS)
labels_val = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels_val, NUM_LABELS)

print('Labels train shape: {}'.format(labels_train.shape))

### Creating the model and training

resnet = Sequential([
  ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(WIDTH, HEIGHT, N_CHANNEL))),
  Dense(NUM_LABELS, activation='softmax')
])
resnet.layers[0].trainable = False

resnet.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['acc'])
resnet.fit(x=imgs_train, y=labels_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NUM_EPOCH, validation_data=(imgs_val, labels_val))

# predictions = resnet.predict(x=imgs_test)
```

And here's the data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dbr0bYFX40HoAJetAIDSh7Zsc-O5JbGS?usp=sharing

If anybody reads this, thanks. I appreciate your time.

Comment: If you've already solved your problem, consider adding the solution as an answer instead of as an edit of the question so that you can set it as solved and other people can also find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a Flatten() layer in between the ResNet50 and the Dense layer and the error is gone! This is the code for creating the model now:

```
resnet = Sequential(
    [
     ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(WIDTH, HEIGHT, N_CHANNEL))),
     Flatten(),
     Dense(NUM_LABELS, activation='softmax')
    ]
)
```